# connection to sql server from weblogic 12c

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, weblogic, datasource, weblogic12c

I developed an application that exposes web services, that application is deployed in weblogic 12c, I call the web services from a java web client, when I run the java client throws this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is: 
    javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [sqlServer].
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'sqlServer'. Resolved ''; remaining name 'sqlServer'
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:178)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:111)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
    at $Proxy34.loginService(Unknown Source)
    at main.Main.loginService(Main.java:32)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

I configure a jdbc resource in Administration Console of Weblogic 12c and the JNDI is named sqlServer... In the application have too a persistence unit xml file, that is the following:

```
<persistence-unit name="BancaSimulacionIBancariaPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>sqlServer</jta-data-source>
    <class>entities.Account</class>
    <class>entities.Bank</class>
    <class>entities.BeneficiaryBankItself</class>
    <class>entities.BeneficiaryThird</class>
    <class>entities.CreditCard</class>
    <class>entities.Movement</class>
    <class>entities.RuleType</class>
    <class>entities.ServiceBank</class>
    <class>entities.TransactionRule</class>
    <class>entities.UserApplication</class>
    <class>entities.Money</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://servertb:1433;databaseName=BancaSimulacion"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="(*******)"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
    </properties>
```

I put the driver `sqljdbc4.jar` in the `wl_server/lib` folder and configure the `commEnv.cmd`... I replace the `64sqljdbc.dll` for `sqljdbc.dll` in the same folder `wl_server/lib`...

But I dont know which is appropriate settings for connection with my database... I test my database and is correct... What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your data source has a target set - otherwise WebLogic won't know about it and it'll throw nasty JNDI (NameNotFoundException) errors.

Basically, your data source connection has to be 100% correct and functional in order for WebLogic to accept and use it - and that includes ensuring it has a valid target set.